# List all shared pages

Tags: notion-api

How can I get a list of all shared with integration pages.
The only way I can implement it now is to use Search API.
It means that if I want to show to the user a list of their Notion pages on my website after authorization, the user should pick the pages, authorize and then wait until indices will be able to serve me them through Search API.

Comment: Hello, how did you end up solving this issue? I am facing the same problem and don't necessarily want to rely on the `search API`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The search endpoint is the only way to return the list of all pages and databases that have been shared with a given Notion integration.

Answer (score 0):

I think your guess is right. There is also a callout on the https://developers.notion.com/reference/get-databases that suggests you to use the `search` endpoint. I would say that the a newly created item will be returned immediately by the `list databases`, whilst `search` will be delayed because of the indexing process. But in the opposite, search supports text matching (ie. will return only pages matching a query string).